# Problems updating a row-table (data grid) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, datagrid, html-table

I'm trying to edit a row in a table(data grid). **The problem is:** that instead of updating the **clicked** row I creating a new one. **What I want to to is to update the row that I click in a modal-window,** I can't make it happen... It seems like I missing a representation of that row in my function corresponding to the modal-window when I press the "save-btn" right?

Here is the file: http://jsbin.com/iyubox/2/

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="main-table" class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr class="box_round">
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Entry</td>
                <td>Invoice</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a class="inData" href="">17.17.17</a></td>
                <td><a class="inData" href="">50123</a></td>
                <td><a class="inData" href="">Invoice</a></td>
                <td><a class="inData" href="">Hola señor</a></td>

              <td><a class="deleteItem" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
              <td><a href="#secondModal" role="" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
<!--
*************************************************************************
<!--
*************************************************************************
-->
        <div id="secondModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button style="position: relative; left: 27px; top: -23px; opacity: 1" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><img src="gfx/btn-close-popup.png" alt=""/></button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Day book</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="FormItems">
                        <ul>
                            <div class="box">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="innerBox innerFloat"><p>Type</p><input class="in-type input-small" type="text" >
                                </li>
                                <li class="innerBox innerFloat"><p>Entry</p><input class="in-entry input-small" type="text" >
                                </li>
                                <li class="innerBox"><p>Date</p>
                                    <input class="in-calender input-small datepicker" type="text" style="">
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="box">
                                <ul>

                                    <li class="innerBox"><p>Text</p><input id=".text" class="in-text input-medium" type="text"/></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn real" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JQUERY

```
function deleteItem(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    console.log('working');
}

$('#main-table').on('click', '.deleteItem', deleteItem);



$('#main-table').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var entry, calender, amount, text, currency, account_no, invoice, contra_account;
     var row = $(this).parents('tr');

         var getData_obj = {

            calender : $('#main-table .inData:eq(0)').text(),
            entry : $('#main-table .inData:eq(1)').text(),
             text : $('#main-table .inData:eq(3)').text(),
            amount : $('#main-table .inData:eq(4)').text(),
            account_no : $('#main-table .inData:eq(5)').text(),
            contra_account : $('#main-table .inData:eq(6)').text(),
            currency : $('#main-table .inData:eq(7)').text()
        }


    $('#secondModal .in-calender').val(getData_obj.calender);
    $('#secondModal .in-entry').val(getData_obj.entry);
    $('#secondModal .in-text').val(getData_obj.text);

    $('#secondModal .btn-primary').on('click', function(){

        var secondData_obj = {

            calender : $('#secondModal .in-calender').val(),
            entry : $('#secondModal .in-entry').val(),
            val :$('#secondModal .in-val').val(),
            text: $('#secondModal .in-text').val()
        }

        $('#main-table tbody').append(
                '<tr>' +
                        '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.calender+'</a></td>'+
                        '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.entry+'</a></td>' +
                        '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.invoice+'</a>' +
                        '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.text+'</a>' +

                        '<td><a class="deleteItem" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>'+
                        '<td><a href="#secondModal" role="" class="" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></td>'+

                        '</tr>'
        );

    });




}

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I came up with a solution not using ID:s, it's not the best solution though, for next solution I'll be using JSON with a whole array of objects I think.

Pls have a look at this file if u need help with something similar u're doing:
http://jsbin.com/onacow/1/

OBS: It's not the same HTML (saved some time) but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `append`, which just adds a new `tr` tag to the table. You need to find a way to select the exact `tr` tag you are trying to edit, remove its contents and then append on the new information.

From looking at your code if you replace this...

```
$('#main-table tbody').append(
            '<tr>' +
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.calender+'</a></td>'+
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.entry+'</a></td>' +
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.invoice+'</a>' +
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.text+'</a>' +

                    '<td><a class="deleteItem" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>'+
                    '<td><a href="#secondModal" role="" class="" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></td>'+

                    '</tr>'
    );
```

With this...

```
  var tableBody = document.getElementById('main-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody');
  var tableRow = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');


                  tableRow[0].innerHTML = '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.calender+'</a></td>'+
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.entry+'</a></td>' +
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.invoice+'</a>' +
                    '<td><a class="inData" href="">'+secondData_obj.text+'</a>' +
                    '<td><a class="deleteItem" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a> </td>'+'<td><a href="#secondModal" role="" class="" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></td>';
```

You will edit the row instead of adding a new one but this isn't a perfect solution. You still need to a way to id the row you want to edit when you click on the edit icon in order for this to work properly.

Hope this helps.